# Program isn't creating file using name specified on the command line

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, fopen, getopt

For this program I am supposed to either write my name to the terminal or to the output file given by the user(`case 'f'`).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // no output file print to screen, print name to terminal
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        fprintf(stdout, "name\n");
    }
    //print name to output file given by user
    else
    {
        int option;
        int fFlag = 0;
        while ((option = getopt(argc, argv, "f:")) != -1)
        {
            //if case 'f' print to output file
            switch (option)
            {
                case 'f':
                    fFlag = 1;  // flag indicates writing name to file
                    break;
                    //case f or error
                case '?':
                    printf("error");
                    break;
            }
        }
        //write to name to output file
        if (fFlag)
        {
            FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "w");
            fprintf(file, "name");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My code works when I want to write my name to the terminal, but it doesn't work when I want to write my name to the file given by the user. The code compiles and runs, but the file just doesn't exist.

The file in the command line might not already exist. Am I supposed to create the file in the program?

I understand what I was doing wrong. Thank you to everyone!

Comment: Did you (a) check that `argv[1]` contains the file name you're trying to open for write-access, (b) check that `file` is non-NULL before trying to write to it, and (c) assuming both of those pan out, ensure the *current working directory* where your program is executing established the file you tried to create? Right now, (a) and (b) seem potential candidates, the latter a prime example of violating [Spencer's Sixth Commandment](http://www.seebs.net/c/10com.html)

Comment: With re-formatted code, it appears `fprintf(file, "name");` is only within the the `argc < 2`  case

Comment: In addition to previous comment, I think you also forgot to do fclose(file) after writing.

Comment: Btw, [`getopt` requires `<unistd.h>`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html), which you also seem to have omitted. It's important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to what the commenters have said, you are using [`getopt`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Using-Getopt.html) for part of your parsing so should use it for the rest!

```
int main...
char *filename;    /**1**/
...
  case 'f': 
    fFlag = 1;
    filename = optarg;  /**2**/
....
  FILE *file = fopen(filename , "w");  /**3**/
```

Explanation: the `f:` to `getopt` means that `getopt` is going to try to find the option that goes along with the `f`.  In the `getopt` loop, case `'f'`, that option is put in the variable `optarg`.  At least for GNU getopt, that is a pointer into `argv`, so you don't have to copy it.  You can just stash its pointer value (at `*2*` above) into a variable you have created for the purpose (`*1*`).  Then you can open that particular file without regard to where it is in `argv` (`*3*`).  See the treatment of option `c` in the [GNU getopt example](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Example-of-Getopt.html#Example-of-Getopt).

**Edit** You haven't shown the command line you're using, but I am guessing it's something like

```
./foo -f my-output-file.txt
```

— in which case `argv[1]` is `-f` and `argv`*`[2]`* is `my-output-file.txt`.  (`argv[0]` is the name of your executable.)  Hence `fopen(argv[1], ...)` is not what you want ;) .